# after effects - circular trim path

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have an animated circle shape layer with trim paths applied to it and the end percent animated from 0% to 100%. But half way through the animation, the circle path seems to close itself. How can i fix this?

`if the circle animation is somehow not visible here, here is the link to imgur:` https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zszj.jpg

[image: circle shape with trim paths]

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/how-to-use-after-effects-trim-path-with-an-illustrator-path/49975#49975 Not sure, but I assume the amimation of your _mask path_ is not correct...

Comment: its just a simple circle with trim paths and animated end percent

Comment: I assume your mask path is a full circle, try to use an outline as mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: i dont think that is relevant to my question. i am not using a mask. it is a shape layer

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue on my end, but I can offer an alternative method. Another way to create the circle example you've provided is to use a *Radial Wipe effect* on the shape layer:

```
Effect > Transition > Radial Wipe
```

Just animate transition completion from 0 to 100 percent. If your shape layer is moving, you may also need to pickwhip expression the *Wipe Center* parameter to your position parameter:

```
transform.position
```

I hope this helps you out. Good luck!